# Stripping EXIF info from uploaded images in Django

Tags: python, django, image-uploading, exif

Is there a way to strip EXIF info from images in Django upon user upload? Right now I am having an issue where user uploaded photos are being rotated when uploaded due to the EXIF info.

I understand python libraries exist for doing this, but was wondering if there is a "Django" way of doing this. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Django itself uses PIL for handling images. What's the problem in using another library?

Comment: What app is rotating the images? Maybe there is a settings to tell the app to stop doing that.